# How to set user permissions for a tree (adjacency-list) structure database?

Tags: mysql, permissions, tree, adjacency-list

We are using mysql. Suppose we have a Adjacency List model table. (I know it's not normalized.) For example, personnel table with fields like:

```
Personnel
|employee|boss    |salary|
--------------------------
|CEO     |null    |999999|
|boss1   |CEO     |99    |
|boss2   |CEO     |99    |
|slvdrvr1|boss1   |9     |
|slvdrvr2|boss1   |9     |
|slave1  |slvdrvr1|1     |
|slave2  |slvdrvr1|1     |
|slave3  |slvdrvr1|1     |
|slave4  |slvdrvr2|1     |
|slave5  |boss2   |1     |
|slave6  |boss2   |1     |
```

We also have a table with some users. For example,

```
Uers
|userid|role   |
----------------
|super1|b1     |
|super2|b2     |
|user1 |sd     |
|ruut  |admin  |
```

Suppose salary information is confidential. So, some users can see salary information from certain branch.

For example, role b1 can see/edit all salaries from boss1 and down. Role b2 can see/edit all salaries from boss2 and down. Role sd can see/edit all salaries from slvdrvr1 and slvdrvr2 and down. Therefore, we need to setup a users-personnel permission table to implement this.

The Personnel table is large with tens of thousand lines.

My question is how do we setup a permission table that we can easily maintain and query?

For example, option 1: we can setup role permission for each personl. But, then the permission table will be huge.

Option 2: we can setup role permission for the parent node only. But, then every time a user wants to see a certain amount of records, we have to look for permissions for each record all the way up to where we have the settings.

Number of users is about hundreds. 
Number of roles is less than 100.

Please ask me questions if it is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To make the life more interesting, consider having  a tree structure among the Users also!

Coming to the implementation, create another table, "User_EMPL_ACCESS", and its should look like this:

Table USER_EMPL_ACCESS(
      User_ID char(..),
      ACCESS_PATH char(..)
)

In the access path, store the fully qualified path of the top most node each user eligible to see.

Then, develop a UDF called hasAccess (userID, EMPLID).

The hasAccess function should do the following:

1. Start with UserID
2. Get the User's Access Paths from USER_EMPL_ACCESS
3. Expand the Adjacency Table into fully qualified paths, using the CTE logic. If your database does not provide CTE, convert Adjacency Model to NestedSet model.
4. Get the Intersection of User Access Paths and the Adjacency Paths, starting from the root
5. If the input EMPLID is the leaf node of the any of the above intersection paths, return 1 else return 0.

Now your queries look like this:

```
    select * from SALARY_TABLE where MONTH = 'JAN' 
    and hasAccess('myUserID', SALARY_TABLE.EMPLID) = 1
```